# How to find ports opened by process ID in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, networking

Suppose the PID of the process is already known

Comment: shouldn't this question be asked at serverfault.com?

Comment: @cd1 it's still unclear to me if this should be proposed to serverfault.com or Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 88):

```
netstat --all --program | grep '3265'
```

- `--all` show listening and non-listening sockets.
- `--program` show the PID and name of the program to which socket belongs.

You could also use a port scanner such as Nmap.

Comment: Hmm..I don't seem to have the --all and --program options. I'm using OSX. Brew doesn't seem to have a formula for it either.

Comment: OSX comes pre installed with nettop though, which IMO is better than netstat for this kind of thing.

Comment: `-n` will dramatically speed things up by not resolving hostnames. `netsta -tupan` is a good default command all and easy to remember.

Comment: 'sudo netstat -ap' is the shorter version of the same.

Comment: `ss -anp | grep '3265'` also works. Command `ss` is part of [iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2), which is alternative to [net-tool](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/net-tools).

Answer (score 31):

You can use the command below:

```
lsof -i -P |grep pid
```

Comment: This one worked for me on CENTOS7 box, thanks @Watever!

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) command line tool with the `-p` command line argument:

> ### **`-p`** (Linux):
>
> Process: Show which processes are using which sockets (similar to `-b` under Windows). You must be root to do this.

The [example section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat#Examples) gives this example:

> To display all ports open by a process with id `$PID`:
>
> ```
> netstat -ao | grep '\b'$PID'\b'
> ```

Answer (score 8):

As a side note, netstat -ao will read the /proc/**PID**/tcp etc to see the ports opened by the process. This means that its reading information supplied by the system (the linux KERNEL), and is in no way directly looking on the network interface or other means.
Same goes for lsof.

If you are doing this as a security measure, you failed. You should never (NEVER EVER) trust the output of netstat, even if you are 100% sure you are in fact running a real netstat program (as opposed to a trojaned version) or any other program that reads the /proc filesystem. Some people seem to think that netstat, ls, ps or any other of the standard unix tools do some sort of magic and poll information from the sources, the truth is all of them rely on the /proc filesystem to get all of their data, which can be easily subverted by a rootkit or hypervisor.

Comment: If you're dealing with a rootkitted system or a compromised hypervisor, you can't trust *anything*, including something that purports to look directly at the network interface.

Comment: I don't think this objection is highly meaningful. Access to the physical network interface/ chipset is mediated by the OS & the OS's network layer; the physical network interface deals mainly with packet buffers & only the OS will know which PIDs are using it. Thus the OS is the primary place to get this info and `netstat` the primary tool. I am sure there are occasional corner cases but in reality, I believe `netstat` is useful including in at least some security situations. This answer could be improved if it suggested a more reliable alternative.

Answer (score 5):

In some embedded devices or with old version of Linux, the problem is `netstat` do not have `--process` or `-p` options available.

The following script shows process with its IP and port, you must be root.

```
#!/bin/bash

for protocol in tcp udp ; 
do 
    #echo "protocol $protocol" ; 
    for ipportinode in `cat /proc/net/${protocol} | awk '/.*:.*:.*/{print $2"|"$3"|"$10 ;}'` ; 
    do 
        #echo "#ipportinode=$ipportinode"
        inode=`echo "$ipportinode" | cut -d"|" -f3` ;
        if [ "#$inode" = "#" ] ; then continue ; fi 
        lspid=`ls -l /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | grep "socket:\[$inode\]" 2>/dev/null` ; 
        pid=`echo "lspid=$lspid" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} /socket/{print $3}'` ;
        if [ "#$pid" = "#" ] ; then continue ; fi
        exefile=`ls -l /proc/$pid/exe | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" -> "}/->/{print $2;}'`
        #echo "$protocol|$pid|$ipportinode" 
        echo "$protocol|$pid|$ipportinode|$exefile" | awk '
            BEGIN{FS="|"}
            function iphex2dec(ipport){ 
                ret=sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d:    %d","0x"substr(ipport,1,2),"0x"substr(ipport,3,2),
                "0x"substr(ipport,5,2),"0x"substr(ipport,7,2),"0x"substr(ipport,10,4)) ;
                if( ret == "0.0.0.0:0" ) #compatibility others awk versions 
                {
                    ret=        strtonum("0x"substr(ipport,1,2)) ;
                    ret=ret "." strtonum("0x"substr(ipport,3,2)) ;
                    ret=ret "." strtonum("0x"substr(ipport,5,2)) ;
                    ret=ret "." strtonum("0x"substr(ipport,7,2)) ;
                    ret=ret ":" strtonum("0x"substr(ipport,10)) ;
                }
                return ret ;
            }
            { 
            print $1" pid:"$2" local="iphex2dec($3)" remote="iphex2dec($4)" inode:"$5" exe=" $6 ;  
            }
            ' ; 
        #ls -l /proc/$pid/exe ; 
    done ; 
done
```

The output is like:

```
tcp pid:1454 local=1.0.0.127:5939 remote=0.0.0.0:0 inode:13955 exe=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd
tcp pid:1468 local=1.1.0.127:53 remote=0.0.0.0:0 inode:12757 exe=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq
tcp pid:1292 local=0.0.0.0:22 remote=0.0.0.0:0 inode:12599 exe=/usr/sbin/sshd
tcp pid:4361 local=1.0.0.127:631 remote=0.0.0.0:0 inode:30576 exe=/usr/sbin/cupsd
tcp pid:1375 local=1.0.0.127:5432 remote=0.0.0.0:0 inode:12650 exe=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

With ls you can know the process route.

Example:

```
fuser 25/tcp
```

The fuser command says that the process is: 2054

```
ls -l /proc/2054/exe
```

The process path appears

Extracted from: https://www.sysadmit.com/2018/06/linux-que-proceso-usa-un-puerto.html

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFISQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I've added IPv6 support and made a few fixes. Additionally on my system the octets of the IP address are reversed. Dependencies are only to posix shell, awk and cut.

My Version can be found on 
[Github](https://github.com/wofwofwof/pentest_scripts/blob/master/linux-get-programm-to-port.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh


# prints all open ports from /proc/net/* 
#
# for pretty output (if available) start with 
# ./linux-get-programm-to-port.sh | column -t -s $'\t' 


#set -x

ip4hex2dec () {
    local ip4_1octet="0x${1%???????????}"

    local ip4_2octet="${1%?????????}"
    ip4_2octet="0x${ip4_2octet#??}"

    local ip4_3octet="${1%???????}"
    ip4_3octet="0x${ip4_3octet#????}"

    local ip4_4octet="${1%?????}"
    ip4_4octet="0x${ip4_4octet#??????}"

    local ip4_port="0x${1##*:}"

    # if not used inverse
    #printf "%d.%d.%d.%d:%d" "$ip4_1octet" "$ip4_2octet" "$ip4_3octet" "$ip4_4octet" "$ip4_port"
    printf "%d.%d.%d.%d:%d" "$ip4_4octet" "$ip4_3octet" "$ip4_2octet" "$ip4_1octet" "$ip4_port"
}


# reoder bytes, byte4 is byte1 byte2 is byte3 ...
reorderByte(){
    if [ ${#1} -ne 8 ]; then echo "missuse of function reorderByte"; exit; fi

    local byte1="${1%??????}"

    local byte2="${1%????}"
    byte2="${byte2#??}"

    local byte3="${1%??}"
    byte3="${byte3#????}"

    local byte4="${1#??????}"

    echo "$byte4$byte3:$byte2$byte1"
}

# on normal intel platform the byte order of the ipv6 address in /proc/net/*6 has to be reordered.
ip6hex2dec(){
    local ip_str="${1%%:*}"
    local ip6_port="0x${1##*:}"
    local ipv6="$(reorderByte ${ip_str%????????????????????????})"
    local shiftmask="${ip_str%????????????????}"
    ipv6="$ipv6:$(reorderByte ${shiftmask#????????})"
    shiftmask="${ip_str%????????}"
    ipv6="$ipv6:$(reorderByte ${shiftmask#????????????????})"
    ipv6="$ipv6:$(reorderByte ${ip_str#????????????????????????})"
    ipv6=$(echo $ipv6 | awk '{ gsub(/(:0{1,3}|^0{1,3})/, ":"); sub(/(:0)+:/, "::");print}')
    printf "%s:%d" "$ipv6" "$ip6_port"
}

for protocol in tcp tcp6 udp udp6 raw raw6; 
do 
    #echo "protocol $protocol" ; 
    for ipportinode in `cat /proc/net/$protocol | awk '/.*:.*:.*/{print $2"|"$3"|"$10 ;}'` ; 
    do 
        #echo "#ipportinode=$ipportinode"
        inode=${ipportinode##*|}
        if [ "#$inode" = "#" ] ; then continue ; fi 

        lspid=`ls -l /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | grep "socket:\[$inode\]" 2>/dev/null` ; 
        pids=`echo "$lspid" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} /socket/{pids[$3]} END{for (pid in pids) {print pid;}}'` ;  # removes duplicats for this pid
        #echo "#lspid:$lspid  #pids:$pids"

        for pid in $pids; do
            if [ "#$pid" = "#" ] ; then continue ; fi
            exefile=`ls -l /proc/$pid/exe | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" -> "}/->/{print $2;}'`;
            cmdline=`cat /proc/$pid/cmdline`

            local_adr_hex=${ipportinode%%|*}
            remote_adr_hex=${ipportinode#*|}
            remote_adr_hex=${remote_adr_hex%%|*}

            if [ "#${protocol#???}" = "#6" ]; then
                local_adr=$(ip6hex2dec $local_adr_hex)
                remote_adr=$(ip6hex2dec $remote_adr_hex)
            else
        local_adr=$(ip4hex2dec $local_adr_hex)
        remote_adr=$(ip4hex2dec $remote_adr_hex)
            fi 

            echo "$protocol pid:$pid \t$local_adr \t$remote_adr \tinode:$inode \t$exefile $cmdline" 
    done
    done  
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, was the only option with detailed process info:

```
$ lsof | grep "1234"
```

1234 is the port number I'm looking for.