# What is my web service ports to be allowed in the firewall?

Tags: port, firewall

Due to a virus in the system, one of our clients have made access to internet restricted in their server. We use two web services data on this server (both use a SOAP API).

The client company is asking me for the ports on the firewall they should leave open so we could be able to use those web services only. I'm not good at networks. So how can I get those information?

I need the port or any address from my two services so that they let them pass through the firewall.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but most web services receive connections on one of:

- 80 (http)
- 443 (https)
- 8080 (http)

Most firewalls client should be configured to allow outbound connections to these.

Server firewall MUST be configured to allow inbound connections on one of these (or some other pre-arranged non-standard port).

To work out what ports your existing web server is actually using:
[how to investigate ports opened by a certain process in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942824/how-to-investigate-ports-opened-by-a-certain-process-in-linux)

Its most likely, 80, 443, or 8080.