# How to get port on which an application is listening for packets?

Tags: android, sockets

I've application's pid, how to get port on which application is listening for packets or local port ? I've an application installed in my phone, I can see the port on that app like 192.168.0.12:62301. 62301 is the port my app is listening on. How can I get it pragmatically ?
Thanks.

Comment: 'Pragmatically'? Do you mean "'programmatically'?

Comment: Yeah same same sorry mistyped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942824/how-to-investigate-ports-opened-by-a-certain-process-in-linux  use a ProcessBuilder to drop into the shell . Parse the result of the call (not trivial to sort thru) for the answer

Comment: So how about you correct your post so it makes sense?